# How can I remove duplicate value?

Tags: forms, hooks

I have used custom code. I want to remove duplicate value using distinct, how can I do this? My code is like this.

```
$media_query = db_select('node','n');
    $media_query->innerJoin('field_data_field_media_room_type','mtype','mtype.entity_id = n.nid');
    $media_query->fields('n',array('nid'));
    $media_query->fields('mtype',array('field_media_room_type_tid'));
    $media_query->condition('n.type','media_room_page','=');
    $media_query->condition('mtype.field_media_room_type_tid',$media_id,'=');
    $media_res = $media_query->execute();       
    while($media_fetch = $media_res->fetchObject()){
     $media_year = '';
        if(isset($media_node->field_year['und'][0]) && $media_node->field_year['und'][0] !=''){
            $media_year = $media_node->field_year['und'][0]['value'];
        }
      echo'<pre>';print_r($media_year);
    }
```

Output like this:

2011

2011

2011

2011

2011

2011

2012

2012

2013

I want to remove duplicate values so how can I remove it?

Comment: just add `$media_query->distinct();` after first line.

Comment: $media_node in your example should be $media_fetch

Answer (score 0):

You can try like

```
 $media_query = db_select('node','n')
         ->distinct()->innerJoin('field_data_field_media_room_type','mtype','mtype.entity_id = n.nid');
        ->fields('n',array('nid'));
        ->fields('mtype',array('field_media_room_type_tid'));
        ->condition('n.type','media_room_page','=');
        ->condition('mtype.field_media_room_type_tid',$media_id,'=');
        $media_res = $media_query->execute();       
        while($media_fetch = $media_res->fetchObject()){
         $media_year = '';
            if(isset($media_node->field_year['und'][0]) && $media_node->field_year['und'][0] !=''){
                $media_year = $media_node->field_year['und'][0]['value'];
            }
          echo'<pre>';print_r($media_year);
        }
```

or

you can use `Group By` for that particular column.

Comment: Its not working

Answer (score 0):

Add `$media_query->distinct();` in line 2

Comment: Its not working